# lldb error out of nowhere

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I get an "lldb" error in my Debug Area when I try to run this app but I don't know why, because I didn't change anything. The screenshot up top shows what happens when the app gets automatically closed.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var ScoreLabel: UILabel!

    var taps = 0{
        didSet {
            if taps == 330 {
                print("You have reaches 5 taps !!")
            }
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if let storedTaps = defaults.objectForKey("key") as? Int {
            self.taps = storedTaps
            setLabel(storedTaps)

        }
    }

    @IBAction func ScoreButton(sender: UIButton) {

        taps += 1
        setLabel(taps)
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setInteger(taps, forKey: "key")

    }

    func setLabel(taps:Int) {
        ScoreLabel.text = "Taps: \(taps)"
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the full error, please.

Comment: there is no error which is red marked. When I try to run the app it gets closed and there is (lldb) in the Debug Area. Also the program switches to the editor and highlights the line of super.viewDidLoad in green and says "Thread 1 breakpoint 2.1"

Comment: look at the picture

Comment: You set a breakpoint on that line (the blue arrow thing in the left column) to tell the debugger to stop there.  Just remove the breakpoint.

Comment: there is no error on the image you added.

Answer (score 0):

You have set a breakpoint in your code most probably unintentionally. Just hold and drag it out till you see an 'X' to remove that breakpoint or right click on it and delete/disable breakpoint.